# Index view and execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I created an indexed view that joined a number of tables to get better performance, but when I use the indexed view, the performance is not better than before. When I survey the execution plan, I don't see any change between the view and the indexed view on these joined tables.

Comment: Put (noexpand) hint after view name in from: `select * from a_view (noexpand)`

Comment: Maybe the columns you chose for index are not optimal, you could review the Database Engine Tuning Advisor's recommendations for your view.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinovic, Tanks a lot. But I use this index view in Entity Framework. How I can put hint for index view in Entity Framework.

Comment: I don't know. Hint is only needed in a query involving joins, though.

Comment: One workaround suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3135695/15498) (for Linq to SQL, but should work the same) is to create a second view that just selects from the first view and specifies the `NOEXPAND` hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using sql server enterprise edition (see feature [Automatic use of indexed views by query optimizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)), sql server query optimizer is not taking in account indexed views..

In other versions you can make sql server use it- [With (NoExpand)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

```
Select col1, col2, col3
From dbo.vw_MyView With (NoExpand)
```